# UIAlertView shown in NSOperation - view controller unresponsive

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nsoperation

I have an `NSOperation` subclass that does some heavy calculations. It has a delegate as well.

If the user does not provide correct input, I validate it in the `main` method and through `performSelectorOnMainThread`I create and show an alert (from my `NSOperation` subclass) and then I call the delegate method as such:

```
    -(void) main{
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(showAnAlert)
                                       withObject:nil
                                    waitUntilDone:YES];
                [self cancel]; //I need to cancel the operation
                return; //don't want to finish main running.

    }

- (void) showAnAlert{
   //Create an alert here
   [alert show];
}

And in my VC I have this: 

- (void) aDelegateMethodFromMyOperation{
   [self.textField setEndEditing:YES];
}
```

Now the problem is, once I dismiss the alert, I can't input any text in my textField.... It will show the keyboard on tap... but it won't accept my input... why is that?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps try:

```
[textField becomeFirstResponder];
```

Because you're switching through multiple UI elements in the `NSOperation`, it is possible that full control is not being regained by the text field.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want the text field to become a responder at this point.

Comment: Okay. Just in case though, I'd recommend testing this approach just for grins. It may be your source of error.

Comment: Just tried it, unfortunately same result :( If I remove the bit [aler show]; from the operation queue everything works fine.... :s

Comment: Ah found the issue! I had two nested performSelectorOnMainThread!Thanks though.